# Pre-flight request is triggering in Chrome but not in IE

Tags: appsec, csrf, owasp, vulnerability-assessment

I am testing an app for CSRF vulnerability and i observed that when i generate a Cross-domain XHR POC with burp and try to exploit, a pre-flight request is getting triggered but this is is not happening in IE. I am able to exploit and perform a state change action in Internet Explorer. What is the reason for this behavior??

Comment: Which IE version?

Comment: Its IE 11 (11.1268)